I can't get the original bytes out of a concatenated byte String in Rust
I've converted a file into bytes and have a vec/array of
[68, 114, 97, 109, 97, 116, 105, 99, 32, 115, 97, 120, 97, 112, 104, 111, 110, 101, 32, 112, 108, 97, 121, 115, 32, 73, 78, 32, 84, 72, 69, 32, 68, 73, 83, 84, 65, 78, 67, 69]

When I concatenated this I ended up with the number 4920555689216983877
Now my issue lies in whenever I try to convert this number back into bytes I end up with only the 8 ending bytes.
I tested this with both Rust's default and the BigInt crate and I'm not satisfied with either:
use num_bigint::{BigUint, ToBigUint};
use num_traits::{Zero, One, ToPrimitive, ToBytes, Num};

fn main() {
    let the_u8: u128 = 4920555689216983877;
    let bigone = (4920555689216983877 as u128).to_biguint().expect("might fail");
    let the_u8bytes: [u8;16] = the_u8.to_be_bytes(); //Using a simple array for demonstrated purposes
    let bigonebytes: Vec<u8> = bigone.to_be_bytes();
    println!("Bytes of base u8: {:?}", the_u8bytes);
    println!("Base of BigInt: {:?}", bigonebytes);
}


[dependencies]
num-bigint = "0.4.4"
num-traits = "0.2.18"

I for some reason can't reassemble the original file which is integral to my program but I feel as though I followed all the logical steps for reverse engineering this simplified process. Could someone explain what's exactly going wrong and help me formulate a strategy to counter it?
I asked a similar question before but didn't have the best minimal reproducible example, now that I have gone through the effort of making a separate project to try to reproduce my issues I'm faced with a similar predicament.
This is the function I used to create the singular int to represent all the bytes in decimal format:
fn concatenate_bytes(bytes: &[u8]) -> BigUint {
    
    println!("Bytes: {:?}", bytes);
    let mut result = 0;

    let mut raw_dog = bytes.as_ptr();
    for _ in bytes.iter() {
        

        unsafe{ 
            result = (result << 8) | (*raw_dog as u64);
            raw_dog = raw_dog.offset(1);
        }
    }
    println!("Result: {}", result);
    result.to_biguint().expect("Failed to create uint")
    //Is actually valid ??? ^
}

Many of the comments were made for myself, but I understand if they aren't particularly helpful for you.

I ended up with the number 4920555689216983877 ... are you sure that the data type is number?

4920555689216983877 only requires 8 bytes to represent it, so putting it in a u128 or bigint type isn't going to create bytes when there are none

"When I concatenated this I ended up with the number ..." - you're going to have to explain more how this works, because it does appear that however you got that number only represents the last eight bytes of your data.

@kmdreko I used a function that would concatenate all the bytes into a singular int then I used a hashmap to convert said singular int into another base. I know that I converted the number from the separate base back to the original base once I reversed the hashmap did the process again and ended up with the same number I originated with.

Why are people using unsafe where is it completely unnecessary?

@ChayimFriedman my ide says it's unsafe so I used the unsafe block, Rust Analyzer told me that it was.

Well yes, but you can just use a (safe) iterator. And you even managed to invoke UB with this. Stay away from unsafe as a beginner.

I would, honestly I didn't want to immediately go to stack overflow so I used Chat Gpt to help me but when I got to a certain point I got trapped by the code I wrote earlier. I didn't realize that I was pushing the bytes so there were only 8 bytes left. I've messed around with Rust for a while and done unsafe when I was making a simple kernel a while ago but I assumed my original error was within writing the bytes not within how I concatenated the bytes.
I noticed that my program only worked with smaller values but now I see that there was a safe iterator I could've used in the BigUInt

Originally I was using regular u32-u128 before I went to using Big integers and num_traits.

Your concatenate_bytes function is losing information. The result variable is a u64 meaning it will only contain up to 8 bytes of information. If you put a byte into it, and then << 8 eight more times then that byte is "pushed out" of the result. And thus result ends up only reflecting the last 8 bytes.
If you use a function that preserves all the bytes in a BigUint, like from_bytes_be, then you get a number like this from your original data:
use num_bigint::BigUint;

let bytes = &[68, 114, 97, 109, 97, 116, 105, 99, 32, 115, 97, 120, 97, 112, 104, 111, 110, 101, 32, 112, 108, 97, 121, 115, 32, 73, 78, 32, 84, 72, 69, 32, 68, 73, 83, 84, 65, 78, 67, 69];
let biguint = BigUint::from_bytes_be(bytes);
println!("{biguint}");

571099513965487418103312191225646346334778926396615879607986731592501905638024494155407303787333

Loading this number as a BigUint and using to_bytes_be would return the original bytes.

Yhank you, I didn't realize I was actively losing information by not converting the file to a biguint. I'd use it later in my program when eeconcatensting the bytes but now I see that when I concatenate the bytes I lose information. When I revise my program later today I'll see if this version works better.

I'd also like to say thank you  for helping me consecutively twice
